# Fill polygon on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I fill the path that I've drawn in red?

http://jsfiddle.net/MVXZu/1/

I've tried to use fill but it doesn't fill my path as I want it to - that is to fill in the red outline - but instead it fills only a diagonal portion (comment out the ctx.fill(); to see the full outline I want to fill) The code that's drawing the line is this:

```
//loop through the data
ctx.beginPath();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.moveTo(linePosX,linePosY);
ctx.lineTo((i*cellWidth) + cellWidth + padding,(tableHeight + padding) - data[i].v);
linePosX = i*cellWidth + padding + cellWidth;
linePosY = (tableHeight + padding) - data[i].v;
if(i == 13) {

    ctx.lineTo(linePosX,tableHeight+padding);
    ctx.lineTo(padding,tableHeight+padding);
}

   ctx.fillStyle="red";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.closePath();
```

}

Comment: Why is your beginPath inside the loop?

Comment: Oh that's a mistake - fixed

Comment: Do not put context settings inside the loop.. linewidth etc.. you are not changing it and have to set it only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you were wanting: http://jsfiddle.net/MVXZu/2/

Because you were only running some of the code `if (i == 13) {}`, only the `moveTo` and the first `lineTo` were getting called. This was resulting in a line at the top of the section, but not a box to fill.

I moved a lot of the drawing outside of the loop. It creates the first point in the bottom left of the graph, then the points along the top, then the point in the bottom right. Then it fills in the whole graph after the path is finished.

Answer (score 5):

- Don't put the `beginPath` into the loop
- Don't use `moveTo`, as that creates a new polygon to fill (see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MVXZu/4/), as the result of `closePath()`). You're at the correct position after the before `lineTo` anyway. [Without it](http://jsfiddle.net/MVXZu/5/) it works better…

Here's the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MVXZu/3/

Pseudo-code:

```
ctx.beginPath();
// set ctx styles
ctx.moveTo( bottom-left corner );
for each (point in data) {
    ctx.lineTo(point);
}
ctx.lineTo( bottom-right corner );
ctx.closePath(); // automatically moves back to bottom left corner
ctx.fill();
```