# Fill in outer area of an interior polygon

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm drawing a ship with 4 points in a `shipVertexes` array.
Inside the ship, I'm drawing the same shape smaller with the `stunVertexes`.

Stroking the context yields the attached image. You can see how there's a small ship inside the larger one. (Red ship)

I want to fill in the space between the outer ship & the inner ship, leaving an empty (black) space in the middle.

When I run `context.fill()`, the entire space is filled solid (see Yellow ship).

How do I fill in just the outside of the interior space?

[image]

Comment: Does this question solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838202/fill-polygon-on-canvas

Comment: @quantumpotato check my answer, it clarifies some aspect of shapes filling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use compositing to "erase" the smaller shape from the bigger shape.

[image]

In particular, `destination-out` compositing will "erase" using new drawings.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle='red';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,0);
ctx.lineTo(100,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,150);
ctx.lineTo(0,25);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,10);
ctx.lineTo(80,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.lineTo(20,25);
ctx.closePath();
// use compositing to "erase" the smaller shape from the bigger shape
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
ctx.fill();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
```

```css
body{ background-color: black; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a faster way to do that other than using 2 filling operation and global compositing.

Also note that using compositing for erasing will erase wathever is in the hole of the ship. if there is some decoration in the background that will be lost. In this situation it looks correct because you have an empty background that is showing the body tag color.

Fill operation has two way to understand what is inside the shape and what is outside. The most commonly used is the non-zero rule:

**‘non-zero’ winding**

This winding rule is most commonly used and was also the only rule that was supported by Canvas 2D.

To determine if a point falls inside the curve, you draw an imaginary line through that point. Next you will count how many times that line crosses the curve before it reaches that point. For every clockwise rotation, you subtract 1 and for every counter-clockwise rotation you add 1.

[image: non zero rule]

To apply the non-zero windind to your ship i changed the drawing order of the internal ship to be counterclockwise, and it automatically produces the hole.

If changing the order is too much complicated you can check if your browser support the even odd rule:

**‘even-odd’ winding**

To determine if a point falls inside the path, you once again draw a line through that point. This time, you will simply add the number of times you cross a path. If the total is even, the point is outside; if it’s odd, the point is inside. The winding of the path is ignored. For example:

[image]

for this rule i just copied your original code, and when filling i specified 'evenodd';

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle='red';
//ship copy 1
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,0);
ctx.lineTo(100,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,150);
ctx.lineTo(0,25);
ctx.moveTo(50,10);
ctx.lineTo(20,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.lineTo(80,25);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//ship copy 2
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(180, 0);
ctx.moveTo(50,0);
ctx.lineTo(100,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,150);
ctx.lineTo(0,25);
ctx.moveTo(50,10);
ctx.lineTo(80,25);
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.lineTo(20,25);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill('evenodd');
```

```css
body{ background-color: black; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple is to fill all the ship in red, then fill the inner ship in black :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100, 25);
ctx.lineTo(50, 150);
ctx.lineTo(0, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 10);
ctx.lineTo(20, 25);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(80, 25);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fill();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```